# XAML DynamicResource Not Working In Debug

Tags: wpf, xaml

**THE PROBLEM**

I have a resource in a resource dictionary called `RoundCorner`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PMSpotlightSearch">
    <Style x:Key="RoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid">
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="20" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="2">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#00000000"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                                <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF303030" Offset="0.3"/>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF33962B"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="grid" Value="0.25"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have loaded it into App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="PMSpotlightSearch.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PMSpotlightSearch"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="RoundedCornerButton.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And it **appears** to work in my UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PMSpotlightSearch.SunkenButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Border Width="75" Height="40" BorderThickness="1">
        <Button Name="btnMain" Height="30" Width="73" Content="{Binding Name}" Visibility="Visible" FontSize="12" Foreground="LightGray" 
                Click="Button_Click" Background="#FF292929" Style="{DynamicResource RoundCorner}">
        </Button>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

This produces no errors, and shows up in the preview:

[image: Beautiful...]

Beautiful, right? Here's how it looks in Debug mode:

[image: Bland...]

Like a typical button...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't reproduce this. What's in the RoundCorner Style?

Comment: I've updated the text to include all the markup.

Comment: Works fine for me, with `<local:SunkenButton/>` in MainWindow.xaml. Do you have the UserControl in the same project?

Comment: I do. I use SunkenButton in a DataTemplate for a Listbox. Should that matter?
                `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:SunkenButton Clicked="TopicBoxSelected"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>`

Comment: That also works fine for me.

Comment: Turns out I had to add it to the XAML of the UserControl itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the ResourceDictionary directly to the UserControl. Adding it to App.xaml is NOT enough:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PMSpotlightSearch.GLButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="RoundCorner.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border Width="50" Height="50" BorderThickness="1">
        <Button Name="btnMain" Height="40" Width="40" Content="{Binding Name}" Visibility="Visible" FontSize="12" Foreground="LightGray" 
                Click="Button_Click" Background="#FF292929" Style="{DynamicResource RoundCorner}" />
        </Border>
</UserControl>
```